# black jack game error

Tags: java, class, exception

I have an error in my black jack program. I have been trying for half an hour to find out. it says "The type Card is already defined". and for some reason my deal() function is not working as well. I am posting this again with more information. Can anyone please help? I am a beginner. 
So i have an class named index whose main method is:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    runGame(2);                                 
}
```

Then i have a few methods and then i have runGame:

```
public static void runGame(int n){
    Card[] newdeck=createCardArray();

    Card[] shuffleddeck = shuffle(newdeck); 
    Deck deck = new Deck(shuffleddeck);
    int[] players = createPlayers(n);
    int[] points = createPoints(n);


    for(int i = 0 ; i< players.length - 1; i++){
        Card a = deck.deal();
        Card b = deck.deal();
        updatePoints(players, points, i, a);
        updatePoints(players, points, i, b);
    }
    printPlayersPoints(players, points);
}
```

In that folder i also have a Card.class and Deck.class: If you want to look i have the links below. 
When i run this i get an error i dont know what i did but it changed:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The public type Deck must be defined in its own file
Syntax error on token "}", { expected
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
The public type Card must be defined in its own file
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
The public type Blackjack must be defined in its own file
Syntax error on token "]", invalid (
Syntax error, insert "]" to complete ArrayAccess
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
GIO cannot be resolved
GIO cannot be resolved
GIO cannot be resolved
BlackjackWindow cannot be resolved to a type
BlackjackWindow cannot be resolved to a type
GIO cannot be resolved
BlackjackWindow cannot be resolved to a type
Syntax error on token "}", { expected
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
The public type Hand must be defined in its own file
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
The public type Player must be defined in its own file
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
BlackjackWindow cannot be resolved to a type
BlackjackWindow cannot be resolved to a type
GIO cannot be resolved
GIO cannot be resolved
BlackjackWindow cannot be resolved to a type
GIO cannot be resolved
GIO cannot be resolved
GIO cannot be resolved
GIO cannot be resolved
GIO cannot be resolved
Syntax error on token "}", { expected
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

at Card.<init>(fullblk.java:4)
at index.createCardArray(index.java:19)
at index.runGame(index.java:104)
at index.main(index.java:3)
```

But for some reason this time i am getting this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The constructor Deck(Card[]) is undefined
    The method deal() is undefined for the type Deck
    The method deal() is undefined for the type Deck

    at index.runGame(index.java:101)
    at index.main(index.java:3)
```

Can anyone please help me.

> index.java: http://pastebin.com/8x344TN9 
>   Card.java: http://pastebin.com/NLbHBDSi
>   Deck.java:http://pastebin.com/emD75yv0

Comment: I recommend researching the compilation errors you're encountering.

Comment: Tidier duplicate of [Making a card game error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446069/making-a-card-game-error).  It would be better to edit the original question, than open a new one that will be closed as duplicate.  Also please heed the advice already offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brace Problem at end of deck class:

```
public class Deck
{
    // your constructors and methods.
  }
}
```

Comment: got it! that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra closing curly brace ('}') at the end of Deck.java.

Answer (score 0):

well,  you have an extra `}` (closing brace) at end of  your Deck class, remove that closing brace an compile. you should be good.

```
public class Deck
{
    // your constructors and methods.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, i dont think that is the only problem the error still comes up?

Comment: i got it fixed by removing the deck class

Comment: @user1796681 removing the Deck class??.. dont yo need deck class ??